# CreateDelegate Error: System.ArgumentException Cannot bind to the target method

Tags: c#, delegates, invoke, argumentexception, methodinfo

I have an app that takes the dll of an external app, look into it for a specified class and method. It then gets the `methodinfo` from this external method and tries to then Create a delegate via `Delegate.CreateDelegate`

I constantly get

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'
```

I have gone and extracted the code a bit to make it easier to share and debug as well as write a small simple external app to read from. See the code below:

**External App Example as Library (.Net Framework 4.8)**

```
using System;

namespace MethodLib
{
    public class PrintText
    {
        public string Print(string textToPrint, int number)
        {
            return $"{ PrintPrivate(textToPrint) }: {number}";
        }

        public static string PrintStatic(string textToPrint)
        {
            return textToPrint;
        }

        public void PrintVoid(string textToPrint)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(textToPrint);
        }

        private string PrintPrivate(string textToPrint)
        {
            return $"This is { textToPrint }";
        }
    }
}
```

**App to CreateDelegate**

*MethodInfo Creation*

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DelegateApp
{
    public class PluginSupport
    {
        public MethodInfo GetMethodInfo(string methodName, string externalLocation)
        {
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.LoadFrom(externalLocation)
                .GetType("MethodLib.PrintText"));

            var methodInfo = instance.GetType()
                .GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);

            return methodInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

*Create Delegate Part*

```
namespace DelegateApp
{
    public class MethodGenerator
    {
        private PluginSupport _pluginSupport;

        public MethodGenerator()
        {
            _pluginSupport = new PluginSupport();
        }

        public MethodDetails Create(string methodName, string path)
        {
            var method = _pluginSupport.GetMethodInfo(methodName, path);

            if (Equals(method, null))
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Method '{ methodName }' doesn't exist in class");
            }

            return new MethodDetails
            {
                MethodName = method.Name,
                ComponentName = method.DeclaringType.Name,
                FriendlyName = method.DeclaringType.Name,
                Parameters = method.GetParameters(),
                LogicalPath = method.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location,
                Method = (Func<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>), method)
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**What have I tried**

So reading a lot of different post I gather that the call I am using

`(Func<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>), method)` is actually meant for static methods only, and as I am interested in all the public methods I am missing a target/instance.

So from other examples, you need to create the instance and pass that in as well, so I used the `var myInstance = Actovator.CreateInstance` and then passed this variable in as well, ending up with the following

`(Func<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>), myInstance, method)`

I have also tried to use this one

`public static Delegate CreateDelegate(Type type, Type target, string method, bool ignoreCase);`

All of this keeps throwing

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.'
```

The only time I get it to work, is when I do the following:

`methodName = PrintStatic` from external app

```
var methodInfo = instance.GetType()
                .GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

var deleg = (Func<string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>),null, method)
```

of course this is not what I want as this only does the static for me and I want the non-static as well. But even with this if I add `BindingFlags.Instance` to the mix the static will also throw the same error.

If I also remove `BindingFlags.Instance` and my `methodName = Print`, then methodInfo is null.

**My Questions**

1. What am I not understanding/missing with regards to the `Delegate.CreateDelegate`?
2. What code am I missing that this is not working as I am expecting?
3. Is there a different way to do the same thing?
4. From creating the Delegate I want to invoke it later in the code, but is there a penalty for just using the invoke directly on methodinfo instead of creating a delegate then invoking it?
5. Why does methodinfo not give me my public non-static member if `BindingFlags.Instance` is omitted?

Comment: What happens if you do `method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string, string>), instance)`? You are using the wrong types e.g. `Print` needs to use `Func<string, int, string>`

Comment: @Charlieface thanks for the feedback. This part `Func<string, int, string>` helped a lot. I will give a more elaborate answer to how code looks like now with it working. I now basically have `Delegate.CreateDelegate(Func<string, int, string>, instance, methodinfo)`

To answer the question you asked, instance is an object and the second param for create delegate expects methodinfo

Comment: You need to decide what function signature you expect ie what parameters and return types. You have to have a delegate with the same signature. `PrintStatic` and `PrintPrivate` are the same `Func<string, string>` but `PrintVoid` wants an `Action<string>`

Comment: @Charlieface thank you. You have been a great help. Even though the real code won't care for the void, your answer was very helpful. I will create an answer with final code and your help for anyone who might need it in future. In nutshell I ended up with this `Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateFunc.MakeGenericType(types.ToArray()), instance, method);`

Comment: I was going to say, if you don't know the type, there isn't much point to the delegate. The whole point of `CreateDelegate` is to have a static-typed delegate to use without reflection, but this way you would need reflection to call the delegate also.

Comment: For this example app I wrote some "extravagant" code to say the least. For the actual usage of the code I will need to see if we know the type upfront or not and see if it is worth the effort. Thanks again @Charlieface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **@Charlieface**, I realised my signature types were not corresponding to me creating the delegate.

So what I finally ended up with in this example code was to do the following in `MethodGenerator` class

1. Get the `parameters` from methodinfo
2. Go through the params and add them to a list of Types and get the type of each param
3. Build a `func` where I do not know the number of types it will need and replace the number with the amount of params I have from methodinfo + output type
4. Check if method `isstatic` and based on this set it to

```
methHead = method.IsStatic
                ? Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateFunc.MakeGenericType(types.ToArray()), null, method)
                : Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateFunc.MakeGenericType(types.ToArray()), instance, method);
```

This is a bit of elaborate code I guess, but it works and will need to refine it or drop it in the actual code base where we want to use it. But as **@Charlieface** mentioned `if you don't know the type, there isn't much point to the delegate.`

**Final piece of code**

```
 public MethodDetails Create(string methodName, string path)
        {
            var method = _pluginSupport.GetMethodInfo(methodName, path);

            if (Equals(method, null))
            {
                throw new KeyNotFoundException($"Method '{ methodName }' doesn't exist in class");
            }

            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(method.DeclaringType);

            List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
            var methodPrams = method.GetParameters();
            
            foreach (var item in methodPrams)
            {
                types.Add(Type.GetType(item.ParameterType.UnderlyingSystemType.FullName));
            }

            var funcType = typeof(Func<>);

            var delegateFunc = Type.GetType(funcType.FullName.Replace("1", (methodPrams.Length + 1).ToString()));

            Delegate methHead;

                types.Add(typeof(string));

            methHead = method.IsStatic
                ? Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateFunc.MakeGenericType(types.ToArray()), null, method)
                : Delegate.CreateDelegate(delegateFunc.MakeGenericType(types.ToArray()), instance, method);          

            return new MethodDetails
            {
                MethodName = method.Name,
                ComponentName = method.DeclaringType.Name,
                FriendlyName = method.DeclaringType.Name,
                Parameters = method.GetParameters(),
                LogicalPath = method.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location,
                Method = methHead
            };
        }
```